# What does "seam" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

As you know "[seam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seam)" has several different definitions in English.
But I can't understand its meaning in [this context](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2016/02/how-to-deal-with-seams.html):

> **How to deal with seams**
>
> a. There is no seam. We've finessed the seam so
>   thoroughly, you can't even tell. This doctor knows everything about
>   the situation as seen by the last doctor, no need to worry about the
>   handoff. You can't tell where one part of the railing ends and the
>   other begins. Your place in the queue and your records and your status
>   are so clear to the next agent that it won't matter a bit to you that
>   there was a switch.
>
> b. There is a seam. That was one color, this is a different one. That
>   was yesterday, this is today. She was your last teacher, I'm your new
>   teacher.
>
> As you might have guessed, the problematic area is where you try to
>   hide a seam, and you fail.
>
> Seams are a promise, an opportunity, a fresh start. Own them or make
>   them invisible.

Comment: In the above text *seam* is used to mean a joint or junction between two different pieces.

Answer (score 1):

A seam can be used metaphorically to describe any sort of discontinuity. In the first case, a patient is transferred from one doctor to another: there is a discontinuity in treatment. In the second case it refers to a change in teachers.

The general idea of the extract is that the two ways of dealing with a discontinuity or change are either to make the impact of the change as small as possible (make the seam invisible) or to present the change as a fresh start and be clear that things will be different after the change has taken place.